# Set two different font for Western fonts and Chinese fonts in Mathematica?

Tags: fonts

There are Chinese and Western charcter in a string. Is there a way to set different font for them? For example:

```mathematica
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 5, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"横坐标", "y axis"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> {"SimSun"}]]
```

[image: Plot[Sin[x], {x, 5, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"横坐标", "y axis"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> {"SimSun"}]]]

How to set western font to be **Times New Roman**? And why there is a rectangle here?

Comment: Maybe `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 5, 10}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["横坐标", FontFamily -> "SimHei", Blue, 20], 
   Style["y axis", FontSlant -> Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", Red, 
    14]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> {"SimSun"}], 
 PlotHighlighting -> None]`

Comment: @cvgmt  If there is Chinese and western characters in one string?

Comment: Use Mathematica package`MaTeX`( set the TeX engine be
 XeLaTeX)

Answer (score 2):

`FontFamily` does not support a list of fonts to be used as a fallback.  The only way to achieve what you are looking for is to break up the text into separate runs using different styles.